# How to call route using ajax in ember

Tags: node.js, ember.js

I am using controller and send a call to route using ajax but in route i could not get any value in req.body . example i  mention:

```
App.StudentController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  // initial value
  isExpanded: false,
  actions: {
    studentLogin: function() {
      var data = {"rollnumber":this.get("rollnumber"),"password" :this.get("password")};
      Ember.$.ajax({
      url: '/rollnumber',
      method: "GET",
      contentType: 'application/json',
      data: data,
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
     }
    });
    },
}
});
```

and route is:

```
 router.get("/rollnumber",function(req,res,next) {
    console.log(req.body);
    var roll = {"rollnumber":req.body.rollnumber};
    console.log("test get data",roll);
});
```

IN req.body i get {} Json .

Comment: What's is router.get? Where did you find that api? Is that pretender? That's unrelated to your question, but to get a hash or properties from an ember object user this.getPriperties('rollNumber', 'password') instead of building the hash yourself

Comment: What happens if you change 'GET' request to 'POST'?

Comment: Post request Is working fine because post route accept data in req.body but  GET not accept

Comment: There is your answer